# Items not adding to the shopping list

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to make a shopping list site where when the user types something into the form, a list is shown underneath it, similar to [this website](http://scottstephensmith.github.io/complete.ly/). My JavaScript code is below, while my HTML and CSS are in the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q6732k01/):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function addItem() {
        $(".typehere").keyup(function(event) {
            if (event.which == 13) {
                displayItem();
            }
        });
    }
    function displayItem() {
        var item = $(".typehere").val();
        var work = '<li><p>'+item+'</p><button>Completed</button><button>Remove</button></li>';
        $(".listed-items").prepend(work);
        $(".typehere").val('');
    }
});
```

Comment: FYI try to be more descriptive in the subject line

Comment: What is the problem with your code? It doesn't do what you expect it to do?

Comment: Please post the full description of problem and correct title instead of saying to check your code...Here, we are not free to check everyone's code.

Answer (score 0):

Your code for handling input submiting is incorrect:

- event handler is wrapped with not-called `addItem` function
- default behaviour for sumbiting is not prevented
- hanging on `keyup` instead of `keydown` (it is important for preventing)

It should be at least something like:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $(".typehere").keydown(function(event)
    {
        if (event.which == 13)
        {
            event.preventDefault();
            displayItem();
        }
    });

    function displayItem()
    {
        var item = $(".typehere").val();
        var work = '<li><p>' + item + '</p><button>Completed</button>      <button>Remove</button></li>';
        $(".listed-items").prepend(work);
        $(".typehere").val('');
    }
});
```

And [fiddle with this](http://jsfiddle.net/Regent3000/q6732k01/2/).